# Redirect on successful login

Tags: wp-redirect

I am using the following snippet to control redirects after successful logins....

```
add_action( 'wp_login', 'redirect_on_login' ); // hook failed login
function redirect_on_login() {
            $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
            $homepage = get_option('siteurl');
            if (strstr($referrer, 'incorrect')) {
            wp_redirect( $homepage );
            }
            elseif (strstr($referrer, 'empty')) {
            wp_redirect( $homepage );
            }
            else
            {  
            wp_redirect( $referrer );
            }
        }
```

What i want it to do is this...

- If $referrer is www.mydomain.com/?login=incorrect then redirect to the homepage
- If $referrer is www.mydomain.com/?login=empty then redirect to the homepage
- Anything else then redirect to $referrer

I'm sure there is something wrong with my logic as whatever $referrer is it just redirects me to the same.  Am i missing something obvious?

### UPDATE

As requested, here is a bit more of an explanation...

- Somebody goes to my custom WordPress login page at www.mydomain.com
- They try to log in with an incorrect password or username
- The following function runs...

  ```
  add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'pu_login_failed' ); // hook failed login
  function pu_login_failed( $user ) {
      // check what page the login attempt is coming from
      $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
      $loginpage = 'http://www.mydomain.com/login';
      // check that were not on the default login page
      if ( !empty($referrer) && !strstr($referrer,'wp-login') && !strstr($referrer,'wp-admin') && $user!=null ) {
          // make sure we don't already have a failed login attempt
          if ( !strstr($referrer, '?login=failed' )) {
              // Redirect to the login page and append a querystring of login failed
              wp_redirect( $loginpage . '/?login=incorrect');
          } else {
              wp_redirect( $referrer );
          }
          exit;
      }
  }
  ```

This is how the ?login=incorrect gets added, I am probably going about it the wrong way though

Comment: It looks to me like you are not using the `wp_login` action hook correctly. You might want to check the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login). Your `redirect_on_login` function isn't accepting any arguments.

Comment: And to reiterate the comment I left on your previous post - do not rely on `HTTP_REFERER`. It is not reliable, and can be spoofed.

Answer (score 6):

According to [the Codex page for `wp_redirect()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect), you should follow your `wp_redirect()` calls with `exit`.

```
add_action( 'wp_login', 'redirect_on_login' ); // hook failed login
function redirect_on_login() {
    $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $homepage = get_option('siteurl');
    if (strstr($referrer, 'incorrect')) {
        wp_redirect( $homepage );
        exit;
    } elseif (strstr($referrer, 'empty')) {
        wp_redirect( $homepage );
        exit;
    } else {  
        wp_redirect( $referrer );
        exit;
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work, try commenting out your `wp_redirect()` calls and then `echo( $referrer );` to see if `$referrer` is set correctly.

Comment: "exit" did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

What you want: If the GET-var 'login' is set to 'incorrect' or 'empty', redirect the user to the homepage. Else redirect him to whatever the referer is.

But there is no hook like `wp-login`. But there is a usefull hook called `login_redirect`.

And there is a problem: [The PHP manual says about `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will
>   set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a
>   feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

```
add_action( 'login_redirect', 'redirect_on_login' );

function redirect_on_login( $redirect_to ) {

  $homepage = get_site_url();

  // get whatever is stored in the GET-var 'login'
  $login = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'login', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED );

  // if the content of 'login' is in the group (here as array), redirect to the homepage
  if ( in_array( $login, array( 'incorrect', 'empty' ) ) ) {

    return $homepage;

  } else {

    // $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] cannot really be trusted and $referrer can be empty.
    // setup a default location for redirecting.
    // @see: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php
    $referrer = ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) && ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) ) ?
      $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : $homepage;

    // wp-login.php use wp_safe_redirect, this means only pages on the same domain are accepted
    // @see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_safe_redirect

    // get the host of our blog (strip scheme like http:// and https://)
    $host = parse_url( $homepage, PHP_URL_HOST );

    // check if the referrer is on the same host as the blog
    $redirect_to = ( false != stristr( $referrer, $host ) ) ?
        $referrer : $homepage;

    return $redirect_to;

  }

  // if everything fails, return the original value
  return $redirect_to;

}
```

We will end up in this script. At first use the right hook (`login_redirect`). This is a filter and it accept one value, the rediretion target. So our function should return a new or modified redirection target.

In our function get the GET-var `login` and check if it is set to one of the accepted values ('incorrect' or 'empty'). If it is so, set the redirection target to the homepage (site-url).

If not, try to get the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. As mentioned above, we cannot trust this value, so setup a default value if `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is empty or something we can't use.

Finally check if the redirection target (maybe the referer) is on the same host as the blog. This is needed because `login_redirect` use `wp_safe_redirect()` and this function only accept local targets as redirection.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, I am trying to get my head around your code example.  The part I am struggling with is get-var,  how is this set and what is it?  In my version I am adding the ?login=empty etc to the URLs

Comment: *You* add `?login=...`? *Where* do you do this? The example above expect that there already is a parameter `login` (from a link or something else). It does *not* modifiy the url anyway.
Please post the complete code, including the part where you add the `login` parameter.

Comment: This hook is not meant for redirections.